# Malloc rewriting data in another malloc

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, rewriting

im trying to get a file named "konferencnyZoznam" sorted by lines into separete dynamic arrays, and than return them to the main function (so i could use them for anotherfunctions). I am not really sure what is causing the problem, but what i saw from debugger and from outputs, that the malloc function allocates space too close together and than every time the function is called, the data in it are rewritten.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void n(char ***pid,char ***ptitle,char ***pname,char ***pdate,FILE **pFile);
void s(char **id);

int main() {
    int k=0;
    char c;
    char *id=NULL,*title=NULL,*name=NULL,*date=NULL;
    char **pid=&id,**ptitle=&title,**pname=&name,**pdate=&date;
    FILE *file,**pFile=&file;
    file= fopen("KonferencnyZoznam.txt","r");
    while(k==0) {
    printf("which function you want to call ?:\n");
    scanf(" %c",&c);
        if (c == 'v') {

        }
        else if (c == 'p') {

        }
        else if (c == 'n') {
            n(&pid,&ptitle,&pname,&pdate,pFile);
            s(id);
            k=0;  //for some reason it even changes k, so i need to change it back here, so program wont end!!
        }
        else if (c == 'k') {
            k=1;
        }
        else{
            printf("function not recognized, try again\n");
        }
    }
    /*for (int i=0;i<strlen(id);i++){
        free(id[i]);
    }*/
    return 50;
}

void n(char ***pid,char ***ptitle,char ***pname,char ***pdate,FILE **pFile){
    char f[100];
    int pr=1,i=0;
    int ni=0,nn=0,nt=0,nd=0;
    while (fgets(f,100,*pFile)){
        pr++;
    }
    printf("pr: %d\n",pr);
    rewind(*pFile);
    (**pid)=(char**) malloc(pr*sizeof (char*));
    (**ptitle)=(char**) malloc(pr*sizeof (char*));
    (**pname)=(char**) malloc(pr*sizeof (char*));
    (**pdate)=(char**) malloc(pr*sizeof (char*));
    for (int m=0;m< (pr/5);m++){
        (*pid)[m]=(char*)malloc(sizeof (char*));
        (*ptitle)[m]=(char*)malloc(sizeof (char*));
        (*pname)[m]=(char*)malloc(sizeof (char*));
        (*pdate)[m]=(char*)malloc(sizeof (char*));
    }

    do {
        fgets(f,100,*pFile);
        printf("f: %s",f);
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            //(*pid)[ni] = (char *) realloc((*pid)[ni],(strlen(f)+1) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy((*pid)[ni],f);
            printf("%s", (*pid)[ni]);
            ni++;
        } else if (i % 5 == 1) {
            //(*ptitle)[nt] = (char *) realloc((*pid),(strlen(f)+1) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy((*ptitle)[nt], f);
            printf("%s", (*ptitle)[nt]);
            nt++;
        } else if (i % 5 == 2) {
            //(*pname)[nn] = (char *) malloc((strlen(f)+1) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy((*pname)[nn], f);
            printf("%s", (*pname)[nn]);
            nn++;
        } else if (i % 5 == 3) {
            //(*pdate)[nd] = (char *) malloc((strlen(f)+1) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy((*pdate)[nd], f);
            printf("%s", (*pdate)[nd]);
            nd++;
        } else {
            printf("\n");
        }
        for (int j=0;j<100;j++) {
            f[j] = '\0';
        }
        i++;
    } while (i<pr);

    for (int p=0;p<5;p++){
        printf("%s",*pid[p]);
    }
}

// this function is here for me to see which data i can later acces in other functions down the line
void s(char **id){
    printf("%s\n",id[0]);
}
```

and this is how the txt file looks

```
UP12345678
Zaklady proceduralneho programovania 2
Jan Zelenka#A#
202004050800

UP12457896
Deep learning
Jozko Mrkvicka#A#
202004051120

UD12365478
Cloud computing
Jana Mrkvickova#A#Jozko Mrkvicka#K#
202004051030

UP98632541
Metody inspirovane prirodou
Jan Oriesok#A#Jozko Mrkvicka#A#
202004051520

PP96385214
Spracovanie obrazu
Jozko Mrkvicka#A#
202004051200
```

well, i tried almost all that i could. i tried cahnging the size of the malloc, adding or taking away * and pointers, even rewriting the whole n function like 5 or 6 times, and well, im running out of ideas of what to do ...

what im expecting at the end are 4 different arrays (id, title, name and date),
where these values should be there:
id [[UP12345678][UP12457896][UP12457896][UP98632541][PP96385214]]
title[[Zaklady proceduralneho programovania 2][Deep learning][Cloud computing][Metody inspirovane prirodou][Spracovanie obrazu]]
you get the point ...
oh, and i cannot use the global variables :D

thanks for any help you can give me, im really loosing my mind over this thing ...

Comment: `(*pid)[m]=(char*)malloc(sizeof (char*));` allocates enough memory to store a `char *` which is not enough memory to store the string. Since you're using a buffer of 100 bytes, you should `malloc(100)`. Either that, or you should wait until you know the length of the actual string before allocating memory.

Comment: `malloc()` does not allocate overlapping memory areas.  If your program uses a pointer returned by `malloc()` to access outside the bounds of the allocated object to which it points, or after that space has been `free`d, then your progam is **wrong**, so there is no meaningful sense of "too close" in this regard.

Comment: The argument in `main`'s call `s(id)` has the wrong type for the actual signature and implementation of `s()`.  Perhaps you meant `s(pid)`.

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc()`.  Do write your `malloc()` calls this way: `my_pointer = malloc(n * sizeof(*my_pointer))`.  The result is clearer and more robust against code changes.

Comment: `for (int m=0;m<  (pr/5)  ;m++)`  and `malloc(  pr  *sizeof (char*));` are inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much too complicated! When you are trying to code some functionality, it is easier to code simple things and test that they do what you want, then (*incrementally*) add a bit more complexity until you achieve your goal.

Below is a "stripped down" prototype for you to consider. It demonstrates what you might be able to do if you merely load the entire file into a block of dynamic memory. Here the block is "hard coded" as a compile time array of bytes.

It seems the objective is to chop up those bytes into sections of 5 strings each. Notice that there is no need to `strcpy()` strings that are already present in this array (or the dynamically allocated buffer loaded from a file.)

The number of lines in the whole block is counted, then "rounded up" to a multiple of 5 because each section of the source data is stored in 5 lines. (OP assumes responsibility for data validation.) A single array of pointers in allocated, each being set to point to the appropriate string (including 'padding' the last block.)

Here, the rows are displayed, grouped together, like with like. Here the OP could write code to allocate separate arrays for each 'type' of string, filling those as desired.

This is not a full solution to the OP problem, but is meant to point to a solution that does not involve exponentially more heap allocations than one might swallow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int countLines( char *s ) {
    int cnt = 0;
    while( (s = strchr( s, '\n' ) ) != NULL)
        cnt++, s++;
    return cnt;
}

void show( int n, char *arr[], int max ) {
    for( int out = n; out < max; out += 5 )
        puts( arr[ out ] );
    puts( "" );
}

int main( void ) {
    char buffer[] = // Simulate buffer bulk-loaded from file with `fread()`
        "UP12345678\n"
        "Zaklady proceduralneho programovania 2\n"
        "Jan Zelenka#A#\n"
        "202004050800\n"
        "\n"
        "UP12457896\n"
        "Deep learning\n"
        "Jozko Mrkvicka#A#\n"
        "202004051120\n"
        "\n"
        "UD12365478\n"
        "Cloud computing\n"
        "Jana Mrkvickova#A#Jozko Mrkvicka#K#\n"
        "202004051030\n"
        "\n"
        "UP98632541\n"
        "Metody inspirovane prirodou\n"
        "Jan Oriesok#A#Jozko Mrkvicka#A#\n"
        "202004051520\n"
        "\n"
        "PP96385214\n"
        "Spracovanie obrazu\n"
        "Jozko Mrkvicka#A#\n"
        "202004051200\n";

    int i = countLines( buffer );
    printf( "%d lines\n", i );

    if( i%5 ) i = (i/5 + 1) * 5; // round up to nearest multiple. could be simpler.
    printf( "%d lines\n", i );

    char **arr = calloc( i, sizeof *arr ); // one array of pointers

    int use = 0;
    // assign pointers and chop into string(s)
    for( char *cp = buffer; *cp; *cp++ = '\0' ) {
        arr[ use++ ] = cp;
        cp = strchr( cp, '\n' );
        if( !cp) break;
    }
    while( use < i ) arr[ use++ ] = "empty";
    printf( "%d pointers\n\n", use );

    show( 0, arr, i );
    show( 1, arr, i );
    show( 2, arr, i );
    show( 3, arr, i );

    free( arr );

    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
24 lines
25 lines
25 pointers

UP12345678
UP12457896
UD12365478
UP98632541
PP96385214

Zaklady proceduralneho programovania 2
Deep learning
Cloud computing
Metody inspirovane prirodou
Spracovanie obrazu

Jan Zelenka#A#
Jozko Mrkvicka#A#
Jana Mrkvickova#A#Jozko Mrkvicka#K#
Jan Oriesok#A#Jozko Mrkvicka#A#
Jozko Mrkvicka#A#

202004050800
202004051120
202004051030
202004051520
202004051200
```

One could use only 4 pointers for one "region" by detecting and skipping the empty 5th line of each region. This is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Your dynamic memory allocation is all wrong, which is easy to do when you go beyond 1-2 levels of indirection.  I recognize that you are using three levels because you want to use out parameters to return pointers to dynamically-allocated arrays of `char *`, but there are better strategies available.

Before we get to alternatives, however, here are the main ways the current program is falling down:

- The allocated array pointers are stored in the wrong place, because the wrong level of indirection is used.  For example, this ...

  > ```
  >     (**pid)=(char**) malloc(pr*sizeof (char*));
  > ```

  ... should be:

  ```
      *pid = malloc(pr * sizeof(**pid));  // main difference: *pid instead of **pid on LHS
  ```
- Insufficient memory is allocated for the individual strings.  For example, this ...

  > ```
  >         (*pid)[m]=(char*)malloc(sizeof (char*));
  > ```

  ... should be something like this:

  ```
          (*pid)[m] = malloc(MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
  ```

---

But why are you using a bunch of separate arrays of `char *`?  That code is absolutely begging for a structure to represent the entries in the file.  Something along these lines would be much, *much* easier to work with:

```
struct person {
    char id[16];
    char title[64];
    char name[64];
    char date[16];
};

struct person *n(FILE *file, size_t *num_entries) {
    size_t pr;
    // ... compute number of entries and store in pr ...

    // Just one allocation:
    struct person *entries = calloc(pr, sizeof(*entries));  // zero-fills the space
    if (!entries) return NULL;  // always check for allocation failure

    char buffer[100];

    size_t line_counter = 0;
    *num_entries = 0;

#   define WRITE_FIELD(field) do { \
        strncpy(entries[*num_entries].field, buffer, sizeof(entries[*num_entries].field) - 1); \
        printf("%s\n", entries[*num_entries].field); \
    } while (0)

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file)) {
        switch (line_counter % 5) {
            case 0:
                WRITE_FIELD(id);
                break;
            case 1:
                WRITE_FIELD(title);
                break;
            case 2:
                WRITE_FIELD(name);
                break;
            case 3:
                WRITE_FIELD(date);
                break;
            default:  // 4
                *num_entries += 1;
        }

        line_counter += 1;
    }

#   undef WRITE_FIELD

    return entries;
}
```

That's ever so much cleaner and clearer than the original, but it's not quite as robust as it could be.  Like the original code, it is thrown off if the file contains any lines longer than 99 bytes.  Fixing that (in either version) is left as an exercise.